# Rails partial collection empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, ruby-on-rails-3.1, render

I've been trying to figure this one out for about an hour now. I have a partial collection that is indeed populated with member model objects, and when I try to render it using collection:

```
<%= render :partial => 'list', :collection => @members %>
```

In my _list.html.erb the @member_id and @member_email attributes are empty in the rendered html:

```
<%= check_box_tag('selected_member[]', @member_id, false) %>
<%= @member_email %>
```

The view renders correctly and I get 3 member items, but with the id and email blank.

What am I doing wrong? If I try to access the partial member using "member_id" or "member.id" I get "undefined local variable or method `member'", so clearly that's not the correct notation.

Now I've seen a bunch of different examples, but the collection method is the way I need to go. I need the partial to only deal with each member as the parent view has support for grouping members in different ways. If I implement a loop in the partial for each member, I'll have to move the grouping view code into it as well, which interacts with input fields in the parent view. e.g. it would be a mess to maintain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
<%= render :partial => 'list', :collection => @members %>
```

Rails is expecting the local variable within the partial file to be named the same as the partial file itself, in this case `list`.

So instead of `member`, by default it would be `list` like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag('selected_member[]', list.id, false) %>
<%= list.email %>
```

If you want the local variable to instead be named `member`, you should either rename the partial file or use this syntax:

```
<%= render :partial => 'list', :collection => @members, :as => :member %>
```

More info here (Sec. 3.4.5): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Doh, thanks! I guess I just don't get Rails completely yet, even when I've after reading that guide. I mean I do now that you've pointed it out. Thanks again!